# Jinja2 template rendering multiple or single file

Tags: python, templates, flask, jinja2

I just wonder whether single template rendering's performance is better than multiple template rendering's.

What are the cons and pros of single template rendering considering multiple template rendering?

Comment: In what way do you mean muliple template rendering? Such as extending base templates and the like?

Comment: Yes, a base template with **block** and **include** statements beside the other templates. Okay, multiple rendering improves readibility but doesn't that reduce the performance?

Answer (score 0):

There is not any performance loss when using template inheritance,You will have to use it in any  projects because of Re-usability.But that does not mean you can indefinitely inherit because it will have file read overheads.

Comment: So you say, I better work with template inheritance till It get more complicated than usable.